# Include "assets" in your angular 6 library

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-library

It has been weeks now, that I search for a solution.
I created (with ng generate library) a library with the UI in for new webprojects here at work... in fact every `component` in that "`template library`" has the *`ViewEncapsulation.None`* set... I know it's not the way we should use **Angular**, but it would allow us to reuse all the hard work that has been done in previous years.

I want to "pack" the stylesheets `(.css files)` into the `library` in a way that when somebody does an "`npm install templatelib`" he/she'll get all the styles and fonts automatically included in their application, no need to manually copy the `styles` and `fonts` in their **`src/app`**.

I want to give my users an atomic unit in a way somebody just needs to set a **`template-lib-tag`** in their **`app.component.html`** and they're all set... then they would only need to add the **`content`** `components` they want to show/use inside the templates design.

I've tried pretty much everything I could find to "pack" the assets, but I either get errors stating that the **`Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(styles)`**. when I try to add **assets** or **styles** to the **angular.json**... or it doesn't do what I want it to do resulting in errors that it can't find the assets during **ng serve**.

Am I too much demanding of Angular Libraries ?  Or is a library filled with `components` and their `CSS` not an atomic unit that I can `plug` into any other Angular app ?

What am I doing wrong/misunderstanding, and how should we "pack" assets into our library so they travel along when installing the package.

Thanks for clarifying in advance.

Comment: I get the same "data path" error when I try to add an assets clause to the angular-cli options JSON. For now I'm just appending `cp -a /path/to/source/. /path/to/dist` to my build command in `package.json`

Comment: Why you don't go through running multiple apps withing one project? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps

Comment: I'm running 10 apps in one project all share one library file ( so all once loaded and cached for all apps ) and if any change needed in one component ( like a bug in phone input component ) all will change with one build and so ... . but I should write an article about it if you need to know all about what I did ( long story ). I hope i can help you if got any question.

Comment: This question description is not very readable

Comment: How are you referencing the style sheets in your `angular.json` file? I have successfully been able to add style sheets from node modules in apps by referencing the files directly in the `angular.json` file via syntax like `'node_modules/package/path/to/style/sheet.css'` (we have a corporate style guide with css, images, fonts, and js files packaged and distributed via an internal npm repo). Additionally, I created an Angular CLI schematic that takes care of adding all of these files to the `angular.json` file.

Comment: check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59265830/2713029

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were already on the right track with your solution with `ViewEncapsulation.None`. You can make a container component in the library that includes all the styles you need globally. Then use the component as the root tag in your application as you suggest in your post. The styles are then automatically included to the whole page.

Here is how a sample component looks like:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-assetlib',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
  styleUrls: ['assetlib.component.css', 'libstyles.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AssetlibComponent {
}
```

You can import many css files in the styleUrls as you see in my sample.
Then you just add this as the root tag in your app.component template and the styles are applied globally to the whole page. No need to reference anything in the angular.json.

Example app component:

```
<lib-assetlib>
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
<i class="fas fa-stroopwafel"></i> <!--This uses a style that comes from the library-->
</lib-assetlib>
```

Comment: Could this be enhanced to share scss e.g. allow mixins to be shared?

Comment: No because the scss gets processed when you build the library if you put it in styleUrls of the component. You can do that only by adding the scss files with the mixins in the library as assets and then import them in the component scss files where you want to use the mixins from the node_modules/[yourlibraryname] folder.

Comment: I'm using this method - thanks for the inspiration. But I'm struggling as my library needs to use specific fonts ... How can I include those fonts in the Library? (They are in-house fonts so would prefer to package them up rather than specifying a URL)

Comment: You can include a font as a base64 string in the CSS. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26867893/converting-and-rendering-web-fonts-to-base64-keep-original-look). So all you need to do is convert your fonts to base64 and put them inside the CSS styles of the component.