# Angular library asset images are not accessible in consumer app production build

Tags: angular-cli

I have an angular library named common-sec in which created assets folder manually under the lib folder. I used images from the assets folder in my library component named "login".

I have used a login component from the common-sec library in my main angular app.

By running the main app with ng serve, library images of assets folder loading perfectly. But when I build my main app using ng build --prod --base-href /prefix/, none of the library images rendered.

I see it tries to request images at localhost:4200/assets/image.png (return 404)
But I see images are available at localhost:4200/prefix/assets/image.png

Is it a bug or it's known issue in angular-cli?

Comment: Hopefully this helps... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595900/angular-6-building-a-library-with-assets/57278842#57278842

Comment: I answered this in another question. Maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50595900/angular-6-building-a-library-with-assets/57278842#57278842

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an absolute path inside any library component?

Base-href will replace the absolute paths at build time.

The libraries `ng build` process from AngularCLI doesn't allow `--base-href` as a parameter, only for projects. So when you apply it to your project build, the libraries are already built (without replacing absolute paths).

You can use your own script to replace them before building the libraries.